# Accessibility text of the "- Any -" option on HTML <select> element - do i need dashes/marker around the "any" option?

Tags: accessibility, html

For the HTML  element - Do I need dashes/markers around the "any" option to satisfy accessibility? If no markers, does the text have to be a sentence ? What types of text is accessible?

For example instead of:

1. Single markers (seem most common):

```
<select name="place">
  <option value="">- Any -</option>
  <option value="paris">Paris</option>
  <option value="london">Londo</option>
</select>
```

2. Double markers ([Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) docs uses it):

```
<select name="place">
  <option value="">-- Any --</option>
  <option value="paris">Paris</option>
  <option value="london">London</option>
</select>
```

No Marker but generic text.

```
<select name="place">
  <option value="">Any</option>
  <option value="paris">Paris</option>
  <option value="london">London</option>
</select>
```

No Marker - use descriptor.

```
<select name="place">
  <option value="">Place</option>
  <option value="paris">Paris</option>
  <option value="london">London</option>
</select>
```

No Marker - use descriptor with dashes/markers.

```
<select name="place">
  <option value="">- Place - </option>
  <option value="paris">Paris</option>
  <option value="london">London</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing special about the "any" text.  It's just another <option> value.  Having a dash before/after the text will most likely **not** be read by a screen reader anyway since the default setting on screen readers is to not announce punctuation and special characters. A '-' may or may not be announced by default. The screen reader user can control how verbose the announcements are.

What **is** important is that your <select> have a label.

```
<label for="city">Select a city</label>
<select name="place" id="city">
  <option value="">- Any -</option>
  <option value="paris">Paris</option>
  <option value="london">Londo</option>
</select>
```

Don't rely on the value of the first <option> to be your label because once the user chooses a different value, you've essentially lost your "label".